# allow the user to delete the entity which created by him in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

what is the best way which can I add to the following method in a spring boot controller class to allow the user just delete the restaurant he created .

I don't want to add the user id to the path, I want the logged in user to not allowed deleting restaurant which he didn't create.

Note that I extend Auditable to add createdBy to the database mysql

```
    @DeleteMapping("/restaurant/{restaurantId}")
    public String deleteRestaurantById(@PathVariable("restaurantId") Long restaurantId) {
        if(restaurantService.existsById(id) == false){
            logger.info("Error occurred because this restaurant is not found!");
            throw new InternalServerErrorException("There is no restaurant with this id");
        }
        restaurantService.deleteById(id);
        return "deleted";
    }
```

Restaurant.java

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Restaurant extends Auditable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "The restaurant must have a name")
    private String name;
....

}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@PasswordMatch
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 20)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String password;

    @Transient
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter Password Confirmation.")
    private String confirmPassword;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @NonNull
   @NotEmpty(message = "You must enter First Name.")
   private String firstName;

   @NonNull
   @NotEmpty(message = "You must enter Last Name.")
   private String lastName;

   @Transient
   @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   private String fullName;

   @NonNull
   @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter alias.")
   @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String alias;

   private String activationCode;

   public String getFullName() {
       return firstName + " " + lastName;
   }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        roles.add(role);
    }

    public void addRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        roles.forEach(this::addRole);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is **impossible** for spring security to magically know what restaurants that are created by a user.

**There has to be some form of relationship between the user and the restaurant.**

You can either as mentioned before have a relationship between created restaurants and the user that created them.

Or you can have a column named `created_by` in the restaurant entity and then store the users `id` in that column. So that when you fetch restaurants you use the `id` in the `Principal` to filter on restaurants created by said user.

But expecting spring security to solve this for you is not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement One-to-One relationship between User and Restaurant with join table if User is able to create the only Restaurant.

Comment: No, I don't want to do that. I want a way with spring security and can work with any case. But thanks for your effort to answer me!